# Universal Windows 10 app background task timer to get notifications

Tags: c#, push-notification, win-universal-app

I want to register background task which should work even if App is not running, in this task i want to download string from web (empty if no new notifications to show) if not empty then show Push notification. I want to check web page every 15-30 seconds is it possible? If so please help me how. Or maybe any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to implements a background task.
The minimum time between 2 background sync is 15 minutes.

Please refer to this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks#conditions-for-background-tasks

Regards

Answer (score 0):

With [out-of-process background task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) you can create a background task class and register it to run when your app is not in the foreground.

You also could use [trigger maintenance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/use-a-maintenance-trigger) to run you bg task periodically.